# Global Variable loading issue / Angular 8

Tags: angular

Global Variables are not set  during firsttime accesess of the component

I have a service to set the global variables. This service is added to provider of the module and also injected to the component. Component is accessed from a button click. Firsttime when accessed, global values are not set as the service is called after ngOnInit()...Hence I used constructor to set the value...In both the cases behaviour is the same.

Console Msgs are captured:
[image]

```
    export class NewreporterComponent implements OnInit {
  newReporterform: FormGroup;
  fNameGroup : FormGroup;
  fg: any;
  notSubmitted : boolean; 
  reporterNVList: nvsForReporter;
  caseFormNVs:nvsForCase
  constructor( private location: Location, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              _nvmasterService:NvmasterlistService, private nvGlobals : Globals) 
              {    this.caseFormNVs = this.nvGlobals.caseFormNVs;
                  }

  ngOnInit() {     
    console.log('initialized-->' +this.nvGlobals.caseFormNVs)
    console.log("Accessed from component 1 -->"+this.nvGlobals.caseFormNVs);
    this.notSubmitted = false;    
  }
  }
```

Any help on this is highly appreaciated. BTW, can i load the values **one time** when the module is initialized so that different views within the module can just use the values.?
Thanks ASJ.

**Update: String variables from global service is printed perfectly. Above code already have the var and console msg is included to print that**

[image]

**Service:**

```
  @Injectable()
export class Globals {
 constructor( public _nvMasterService:NvmasterlistService){  } 
public caseFormNVs = this.getCaseNVs();
anyVariable: string = 'test';
 public getCaseNVs(): nvsForCase {
    this._nvMasterService.getCaseFormNVs().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.caseFormNVs = res;
            console.log('case form values ready')
        }
    );
    return this.caseFormNVs;
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

You are using `+` to console the object replace it with `,` simply it will print the object.

Happy conding... :)

```
console.log('initialized-->' ,this.nvGlobals.caseFormNVs)
console.log("Accessed from component 1 -->",this.nvGlobals.caseFormNVs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is stackblitz link  [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9si6aw)

For, Global variable you can have two approaches.

1. **In index.html**

   ```
   <body>
        <my-app>loading</my-app>
            <script>
              myTest = 1;
            </script>
   </body>
   ```

   and you can access this in any component .ts file.

   ```
    declare const myTest: any;

    ngOnInit(){
          console.log(myTest);
    }
   ```
2. Using **Global** Service dependency injection.

   Your service.ts

   ```
    export class GlobalService {
        globalVar: string = 'Global Var';
        constructor() { }
    }
   ```

   Access in app.component.ts.

   ```
    constructor(private nGlobal: GlobalService){}
    ngOnInit(){
       console.log(this.nGlobal.globalVar);
    }
   ```

Comment: Yes...am following approach two. It works fine in the case of string vars, but it obtains the value of object after ngOnInit. Could be that service is slow and ngOnInit completes before the value is retuned...?..If so, how to handle that.?...Am updating the latest screenshot from console where string var assigned directly are printed during ngOnInit......Service is on NODE.JS...Thanks

Comment: If your service is in `node.js` then you need to call service in angular service using `httpclient module`. then you have to subscribe in `ngOnInit()` to get value from `GlobalService`.  If you know `rxjs` then there you can use `rxjs Subject `to get `value as a observable` in your `component.ts` class file.

Comment: Yes....thatz there...and subscribing that service is fetcing the global values to the frontend and thatz what is printed on the console....Also note that instead of taking values from service if I directly assign (hardcoded object) this issue doesnt occur.